# How to correct Linux file system permission?

Tags: permissions, boot, elementary-os

I've recently install Elementary OS on my PC and i mistakenly installed a program named "mount management", apparently it changed my file-system permission or i guess it does (because i checked theme with live Linux and all of their owner set to root user) and on start-up it gave me permission denied error:

```
mountall: mount / []:permission denied
```

and bunch of other permission denied errors and it obviously hang.

My question is:

Is there any chown or chmod command which i can run on my linux live(recovery mod is read-only) to correct that partion permission (although i checked them all their owner is root) ?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but what is it you're saying doesn't have proper permissions? The filesystem device (`/dev/sdX`), the mount point (`/mnt/foo`), or the utils (`/sbin/mount`)?

Comment: Just a wild guess... What about `chmod 755 /`...?

Comment: The recovery mode may be *initially* read-only, to allow you to run filesystem checks if you find it necessary, but with `mount -o remount,rw /` or similar, you should be able to lift the read-only restriction when you need to change things.